# How can we use the same Component for two blade.php in Livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am new to laravel8 and Livewire, I have a form that contains many infos that's why I wanted to split the form with fetching data so each one could be in a different page, but the problem is If I do so, I would have to create a component for Fetching data and another one for edit,
Is there any way to use the same component on different blades? or it is necessary that a Component would work only for one blade.php.

Comment: Can you provide any code for what it is you have so far and where you're getting stuck?

Comment: You can use the same blade and component for each function, like a reusable component. Once the form to create and edit are similar and bind same properties

Answer (score 0):

use

```
php artisan make:liveiwre mycomponent
```

and if you want mycomponent you need call like this

```
<livewire:mycomponent/>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but I meant to use all the functionalities that exists in a component in more than one livewire blade...

Comment: I wanna use the functionalities exists in ComponentA in blade1 and blade2